# Loading/Appending JS script asynchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm using Laravel to implement templates based on a main page. Different pages have different JS scripts, so I created a template to import JS scripts:

```
<!-- jQuery 2.1.3 -->
<script src="{{ URL::asset('plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js') }}"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.2 JS -->
<script src="{{ URL::asset('js/bootstrap.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- Ajax Page Loading -->
<script>
    function ajax(url) {
        $('.main-content').fadeOut(100); //hide the page
        $('.spinner').show(); // show a spinner
        $.ajax(url, {
            async: true,
            success: function(data) {
                $('#header').html(data[0]); //append received header to header
                $('#content').hide().html(data[1]).fadeIn(500); //show the page again
                $('body').append(data[2]); //append scripts to body
                $('.spinner').hide();
            },
        });
    }
</script>

@yield('extra-scripts') <--- /* HERE is where the scripts will be */
```

I'm also using AJAX to load only the content without refreshing the page.
The function ***ajax*** will be used to load any url into the div "content". However, I also need to load the scripts so the page works properly.

### Data is an array with three fields:

- 0 is Header html
- 1 is Content html
- 2 are the dynamically added ***scripts***

The problem is whenever I'm loading the page, I get this error:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of
>   its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help,
>   check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

I don't want script loading to affect user experience. Has to be async.

## What I already tried:

- #### jQuery.getScript

  - This solution requires me to move all the scripts to a separate JS file. This would probably solve it, but I would rather keep them all in the respective page.
- #### AjaxPreFilter

  - $.ajaxPrefilter with options.async = true makes the scripts load after the page thus making some properties undefined and not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This warning will continue to happen as long as you inject the script to the body of the document.

I'd recommend using `$.getScript` as this will load the script correctly. I do not really understand why you'd want all javascripts to be in the same page from the first place. 
You probably want to have them in a separate file anyway for easier maintenance down the road and separation of concerns.

You can also use vanilla javascript for that:

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.setAttribute('src','your_script.js');
head.appendChild(script);
```

If you insist on doing it this way - try injecting it directly to the `head` of the document and not the `body` and see if that helps.

On a more general note - seems like you're building a single page application (SPA) - have you looked into JS frameworks like `Angular`, `Backbone`, etc? they will handle all the heavy lifting for you and will help you scale your application better. This smells a little bit like trying to re-invent the wheel and could be a great thing as an educational process but might not be such as good idea in the long run.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Yani. It is in fact a bit of a educational process since I'm not yet familiar with Angular or Backbone. I will probably end up separating the JS.

Comment: I will have to use $.getScript as a fix up and separate files.

Comment: May I take this moment to also ask if having unused additional JS loaded affects performance in any term?
For example, navigating with AJAX loading scripts, where there are scripts loaded from previous page but not used, is that bad?

Comment: It is a very common practice when building a SPA so I'd say unless you have dozens/hundreds of scripts you should be good and I wouldn't worry about it too much. Only thing is make sure you don't run heavy background processes (like for example ajax calls, timer operations, calculations) when not needed. So if you have scripts that are heavy on resources, you probably want to make sure they stop running when not needed, depending on the page you're at.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing right now is not a best practice. If you want to load pages using Ajax and dynamically call the Js files, I would recommend you to use `pjax`.

Take a look at here: https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax

Since you are using `laravel`, you can easily implement this it in `pjax`.

Here is a tutorial: https://laracasts.com/lessons/faster-page-loads-with-pjax

Comment: The problem is I return an array data with three fields, and I'm not sure how you tell PJAX where to place each.